# How can I echo a date so many days from now using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am making a script that will allow admins to ban IPs. I am currently implementing the ban length system, however I am trying to echo the lift date next to each select option.

Here is my HTML for the dropdown select:

```
             <strong>Select Ban Length</strong>
       <div class="select-style">
  <select>
    <optgroup label="Temporary Ban Options">
    <option value="1">1 Day</option>
    <option value="3">3 Days</option>
    <option value="7">7 Days</option>
    <option value="14">14 Days</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Permanent Ban Options">
      <option value="PERMANENT">Permanent - Never Lift Ban</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

What I am asking is how can I echo the lift date next to each item? For example:

[image]

I have started with `<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>` to get the current date but how can I, as shown in the image above achieve something similar where the lift date is beside the ban length?

Comment: Just add one day to today's date. This has been asked here a lot. A quick search will find it for you.

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 day"))`

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+3 days"));`  Oh, haha @MarcB beat me to it.

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+7 days"))`

Comment: Anyway, strtotime is your friend.

Comment: @JohnConde Yes, I felt annoyed that I had to ask but it was mainly the format that I needed.

Comment: @MattKent and despite what everyone seems to have written, that's not the date string you're looking for given your example image. It's `m-d-Y H:i A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use [strtotime](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php)'s automatic `+ n days` ability using this date string `m-d-Y H:i A` to give what you asked for in your example image.

```
<strong>Select Ban Length</strong>
<div class="select-style">
  <select>
    <optgroup label="Temporary Ban Options">
    <?php
    foreach (array(1, 3, 7, 14) as $d){
        // setting $date and $text separately just for readability here
        $text = $d . ' Day' . ($d===1? '': 's');
        $date = date('m-d-Y H:i A', strtotime('+ ' . $d .' days'));
        echo '<option value="'.$d.'">' . $text . ' (' . $date . ')</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Permanent Ban Options">
      <option value="PERMANENT">Permanent - Never Lift Ban</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you'd do it:

```
  <select>
    <optgroup label="Temporary Ban Options">
    <option value="1">1 Day (<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 day")) ?>)</option>
    <option value="3">3 Days (<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+3 days")) ?>)</option>
    <option value="7">7 Days (<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+7 days")) ?>)</option>
    <option value="14">14 Days (<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+14 days")) ?>)</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Permanent Ban Options">
      <option value="PERMANENT">Permanent - Never Lift Ban</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use similar code:

```
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 day"))
```

---

In your case:

```
<option value="1">1 Day (<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 day")) ?>)</option>
    <option value="3">3 Days (<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+3 days")) ?>)</option>
    <option value="7">7 Days (<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+7 days")) ?>)</option>
    <option value="14">14 Days (<?= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+14 days")) ?>)</option>
```

Read more about strtotime function: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp